# How to change OSMdroid tile source to MapQuest

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, mapquest

In XML Mapview

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/OSMap"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In main activity code

```
MapView myMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.OSMap);
myMap.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest" , 16 , 18 , 256 ,".png" , new String[] {"http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                            "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                            "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
                            "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/"}));
```

[image: Output]

I have 2 Questions.

- Is it possible to add MapQuest as source in OSMdroid maps ?
- If its possible then where to add API key for MaqQuest in OSMdroid.

Comment: No, it's no longer possible to use Mapquest as a source of tiles. It used to be but was withdrawn recently. No tile source ever needed an API key, nor does one now

Comment: Your picture already says everything. Choose a different tile provider.

Comment: @scai read my questions carefully :)

Comment: It looks like you can use Mapquest with an API key on an Android device but not through Osmdroid. See https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/

Comment: Does this mean that no custom tile map servers ever be integrated with MapQuest on android map? If not, how can we stop MapQuest map service and include ours in the app? I followed this approach https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/android-sdk/ and now got stucked with linking my XYZ format tile server into it.

Answer (score 0):

My Question may help others. From 11 July 2016 MapQuest stopped providing open tiles access

> users only can access MapQuest tiles using their Android or IOS SDKs

https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Map quest tiles are now hosted by map box. Osmdroid has been updated to reflect the change as of 5.3,which should be cut in a few days. You can always pull down the source of you need the fix now.

You'll need a map box key which is specified in the manifest or programmatically.  See the sample project on github

This issue was covered under osmdroid issue
[#332](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/332) which would have cleared this up sooner.

Relevant code for osmdroid v5.3+

Manifest

`<meta-data android:name="MAPQUEST_ACCESS_TOKEN" android:value="pk...YOUR MAPBOX KEY!.."/>`

Set the tile source

`mMapView.setTileSource(new MapQuestTileSource(getContext()));`